# Wordpress replace args in function within a plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am trying to modify the arguments of a function that is called in a plugin.
The original code within the plugin

```
orplugin_load_template( 'templatefile.php', array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'userdata' => wp_get_current_user(),
        'dashboard_query' => $dashboard_query,
        'post_type_obj' => $post_type_obj,
        'post' => $post,
        'pagenum' => $pagenum
    ) );
```

My try out version that I placed in functions.php in my child theme

```
function my_orplugin_load_template( 'mytemplatefile.php', array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'userdata' => wp_get_current_user(),
        'dashboard_query' => $dashboard_query,
        'post_type_obj' => $post_type_obj,
        'post' => $post,
        'pagenum' => $pagenum
    ) );
```

add_filter('orplugin_load_template','my_orplugin_load_template', 10);

I created my own templatefile.php called mytemplatefile.php. I don't knwo where to store this file outside the plugin. And how to call it to replace it in the original plugin. I want to load mytemplatefile.php in place of templatefile.php. How to achieve this?

Comment: It appears that you're attempting to use a filter called `orplugin_load_template ` and without knowing how the `orplugin_load_template` filter works I'm afraid it would be impossible to answer this question. I suspect the plugin you're using doesn't have a filter and you may have misunderstood what `add_filter` does. It doesn't filter an existing function. As it stands, in this code sample, your function `my_orplugin_load_template` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Good point. You sent me the right direction. I found out that WP has a standard function for plugins : 
<?php load_template( $_template_file, $require_once ) ?>

Answer (score 0):

Good point. You sent me the right direction. I found out that WP has a standard function for plugins :

```
<?php load_template( $_template_file, $require_once ) ?>
```

[https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_template] .  And indeed the plugin has a subfolder templates in which the template.php file is stored.I tried then following code to use my adapted template.php file but got some error messages

```
if ( $overridden_template = locate_template( 'some-template.php' ) ) {
// locate_template() returns path to file
// if either the child theme or the parent theme have overridden the template
load_template( $overridden_template );
 } else {
   // If neither the child nor parent theme have overridden the template,
// we load the template from the 'templates' sub-directory of the directory this file is in
   load_template( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/some-template.php' ); 
}
```

Any suggestions?